# What could I do to optimise this Minecraft Forge code in 1.19.2?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm pretty new to Minecraft modding and would like to know if there's a better way to test for a block in a radius around my player. my current implementation is the following:

```
if ((world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz))).getBlock() == Blocks.TORCH

                                    || (world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz))).getBlock() == Blocks.WALL_TORCH

                                    || (world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz))).getBlock() == Blocks.FIRE

                                    || (world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz))).getBlock() == Blocks.CAMPFIRE

                                            && world.getMaxLocalRawBrightness(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz)) == 15

                                    || (world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz))).getBlock() == Blocks.LANTERN

                                    || (world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz))).getBlock() == Blocks.LAVA

                                    || (world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz))).getBlock() == Blocks.LAVA_CAULDRON

                                    || (world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz))).getBlock() == Blocks.FURNACE

                                            && world.getMaxLocalRawBrightness(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz)) == 13)
```

This basically loops through each block in a radius of 10 and returns true if a block is found. I know there is a way to optimise this code but I can't think how.

My implementation works, but is there anything else I could try which would be less taxing on the cpu?

Comment: you could start by putting 

`(world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz))).getBlock()`

in a separate variable

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using local variables!

```
BlockPos blockPos = new BlockPos(x + sx, y + sy, z + sz);
Block block = world.getBlockState(blockPos).getBlock();
int lightLevel = world.getMaxLocalRawBrightness(blockPos);

if (block == Blocks.TORCH || block == Blocks.WALL_TORCH || block == Blocks.FIRE || block == Blocks.CAMPFIRE && lightLevel == 15 ...) {
    ...
}
```

That makes it way more cleaner, easyer to read and more efficient!
But I don't understand what are you doing with this code!

If you are looking if there is a lightsource around the player, than use only the `if (block == Blocks.TORCH ||...)` and if you are looking for the lightlevel, thann use only `if (lightLevel >= 13)`!

Because if you have more than one mod installed, it is not advisable to go through all the blocks (that emit light)!